# Yii, Load a model of a module from the main app controller

Tags: php, yii, module

I would like to load a model in **booksImported** module from main app controller,
main.php

```
    'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
            'application.modules.booksCategory.models.*', 
            'application.modules.booksImported.models.*' 
         ),
```

In my SiteController function i tried..

```
Yii::app()->getModule('Importedbooks')
```

This only gets the Module name. I also tried

```
       Yii::setPathOfAlias('booksImported','../modules/booksImported/models');

        Yii::import('booksImported.models.Importedbooks',true);  // this will include the class DesiredModel immediately

        $model = Yii::createComponent('Importedbooks');

        print_r($model);
```

which gives an error

```
Alias "booksImported.models.Importedbooks" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.
```

Comment: Is your module booksImported on config/main modules section?

Comment: Yes I have added it in the config/main.php modules array aswell...'modules'=array ('booksImported')